# How to segue push to a Navigation Controller from a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

In `viewController1`, I have a `CollectionView` and used the following code to create a segue to the selected item page.

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "ToEventInfoSegue") {
            let destination = segue.destination as! ViewController2
            let cell = sender as! CollectionViewCell
            destination.eventInfo = cell.anEvent!
            destination.MainVC = self
        }
    }
```

Since the `viewController2` is not currently embedded in a navigation controller, after the segue push, there is no navigation bar.

My question is in order to get the navigation bar, how do I implement the segue when the VC2 is embedded in a navigation controller?

**Update**

1. Tab Bar Controller -> Navigation Bar Controller -> VC1
2. VC1 -> (Currently no navigation bar controller) -> VC2

**Update 2**
After resetting the segue, I was able to get a navigation bar in StoryBoard. However, it seems that it is covered by the view. The navigation bar is not showing up. **The back button does show up.** I think the title is somehow on the bottom of the layer. The hierarchy looks like this.

[image]

[image]

The blue area is where the title of Navigation Bar is. However, as you can see it is covered and does not show when I run the app.   **The back button does show up**

Comment: Does viewContoller1 embedded in Navigation Controller?

Comment: @JimYu Yes, it is embedded in a Navigation Controller.

Comment: In your storyboard, does your storyboard segue (ToEventInfoSegue) use push?

Comment: @JimYu I used show. But I think they are the same.

Comment: Does the flow like this?
Tab Bar Controller --> Navigation Bar Controller --> VC1 --> (Currently no navigation bar controller) --> VC2

Comment: @JimYu Yes! In VC1 there is a collectionView which lists some events data. When you click into one of the event data, the segue leads you to that specific data page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130374/discussion-between-jim-yu-and-woshinibaba).

Comment: you do not need to embed navigation bar to every vc if you connecting other vc from already embedded navigation bar vc.

Comment: @vaibhav I agree. But the navigation bar won't show up.

Comment: show your vc screenshot.

Comment: @vaibhav 
I think the problem is that there are multiple viewControllers linked to VC2.
VC1 is not the only page that can be directed to VC2
Should I set all the segue to push then?

Comment: again please show your storyboard screenshot and specify the vc which is not getting navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question what i understand is you need `NavigationBar` in your `DetailViewController` so for that you have to assign segue to your `CollectionViewCell` with `DetailViewController` like below screen shot.

**I guess your storyboard flow like this:**
[image]

What you need is assign segue from `Cell` to `DetailViewController`:

[image]
[image]

By doing this you can get your `NavigationBar` in your detail screen.

Hope this will help you to slove your problem.

Comment: Hi, the storyboard flow is correct. I think the problem is that there are multiple viewControllers linked to VC2. VC1 is not the only page that can be directed to VC2. Should I set all the segue to push then?

Comment: Ok so there are multiple places from where you navigate to VC2 so what my question is you need navigation bar in all connected segue right ? or only from VC1->VC2 you need navigation bar ?

Comment: In all the connected segue, so there will be a back button to go back to the previous viewController.

Comment: ok fine than do as directed and you will get your navigation bar but make sure you have Navigation Bar enabled in your `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I was able to get the navigation bar, but it is covered under the view. Please see my update. Thank you for your help!

Comment: based one your new screen shot I think you have manually added your NavigationBar if yes please remove that bar, connected navigation bar automatically show on your screen while you push from VC1.